# Model Determination using Wald Test for Logit

Tags: logistic, modeling, model

I am carrying a Logistic regression. I have 13 predictor variables.
When I consider the summary of the data using R, I obtain a table of coefficients:

*Abbrevaited list below*

```
Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      -8.049903   0.647700 -12.428  < 2e-16 ***
male1             0.480925   0.101629   4.732 2.22e-06 ***
age               0.062634   0.006253  10.016  < 2e-16 ***
education1        0.030310   0.106103   0.286  0.77514
```

NOTE: The factor *education* shows a large P-value.

Q. Is it appropriate to rerun the logistic regression without (education) or the other high P-value variables and report this new model in my report, or as my 'answer'. Or is it better to report the full model?

*Sorry for such a basic question, I'm not a statistician.*

Comment: How did you pick your current model that gives those high p-values?

Comment: @Dave In full disclosure, the data is from the [Framingham Heart Study](https://datacatalog.med.nyu.edu/dataset/10046) and the dataset I have contains 14 independent variables and the endpoint being the presence of cardiovascular disease. I used 13 Indep. variables.